# What breaker should I use to protect downstream?

Tags: protection, load, inrush-current

I have a 16A supply connected to a junction box to split into a 16A feed and a 13A double socket.

The issue is the 16A is connected to a load that will have high inrush current.

I have protection for the 16A supply upstream but will there be an issue with anything downstream of the 13A socket due to the load on the 16A side, and if so, what sort of protection can I use?

Comment: You haven't said what the actual symptoms are.

Comment: why do you expect a 16 A power supply to deliver 29 A?

Comment: This probably belongs on DIY, since I suspect that the OP is asking about mains wiring in the UK.

Comment: This will not be household electrics this will be a permanent installation with only about 2A max running off the 13A and 10A max on the 16A feed. I'm concerned that any protections I put on the 13A socket will be tripped by inrush current from the 16A feed, is this true?